# SSRS - How to query report server database for linked report settings, cache settings and snapshot settings

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

### TASK

I'm in the process of setting up a couple of reports for management to view security settings and IT admin to check portal settings for all report and linked report items in the SSRS server.

### PROBLEM

I have already found most of the information I require but I'm struggling with the cache settings, snapshop settings and linked report parameters. If anyone is able to help with sql queries for any of the following I'd appreciate it.

## Q1 - Cache Settings

I'm looking to display whether this is live, expiry on timer (how long), expiry on schedule (schedule name) or snapshot based as per settings located in the web portal when you go to manage report -> caching. This is required for both reports and linked reports. I know the expiry on a timer is in the CachePolicy table but I'm unsure how the schedules tie in.

Source:

[image]

Example result set:

[image]

## Q2 - Snapshot Settings

I'd like to display the schedule name if there is one, how many snapshots are being retained (number or all) and whether people can manually create snapshots or not. These are settings as per web portal when you go to manage report > history snapshots > schedule and settings and would be required for both reports and linked reports.

Source:

[image]

Example result set:

[image]

## Q3 - Parameters

Looking for a list of parameters, whether they are hidden or not and default value. I can pull this from the catalog.content xml for reports but I'm not sure where to locate the parameter settings for linked reports.

Source:

[image]

Example result set:

[image]

Comment: be precise when you ask a question. Follow steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited for clarity. Please let me know precisely what you feel the issue is if this isn't sufficient as I'm happy to provide any extra detail required.

Comment: Just a thought but you could run a trace on the reportserver database then access the data you need via the web portal. You should be able to view the queries that were executed to get the data and work it out from there.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I did actually try that before asking but no luck. There was a lot of activity even in the handful of seconds it took me to change something and while I did go through it to see if I could find what I needed, there was nothing in there that was obviously what I was looking for. I suspect what I actually need to do if I come at it from this angle is to list every function and procedure that is called and go through them one by one which will take a considerable amount of time. I suspect this is what I will end up having to do if noone has the answer already.